# Can I Load Pipe separated text file directly to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a huge ('|') separated text file(1.5 GB) in my local which I need to load to redshift.
I do not have s3 configured at the moment. Is there a way to load this file directly to Redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with John's answer, but I think you are specifically saying you don't have S3.

> I do not have s3 configured at the moment.

will you be able to load to `Redshift` directly without using S3?
Here I'm assuming, by `my local` you are referring the local `desktop/laptop` etc.

Answer is **no**, you can't. But you could do it if you could load the file to any `AWS` computing instance and have `ima` roll enabled to do `ssh` that way, `Redshift` could you a `SSH` to that `AWS instance`, then you should be able to load any size `CSV` with any `delimiter` including `|` as John answered.

I hope this will help.

Comment: I Agree with that. Was pretty sure. Just needed a confirmation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The [COPY command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) has a [`DILIMITER` parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-delimiter), which can specify pipe-separation.